# How to add a custom table to the top-right corner of a ggplot2 plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a custom table (or text) to the top-right corner of the following plot:

[image: Without a table]

so it looks like this:

[image: With a table]

I have tried to use

```
annotation_custom(tableGrob(mynames), xmin=-1, xmax=7, ymin=0, ymax=-1)
```

but it adds the table on top of the plot area and I cannot move it to the top-right corner (above "Legend").

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Mixing-ggplot2-graphs-with-other-graphical-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @infominer I found the solution. This did the trick:

```
ggpl <- ggplot(...)
tableNames <- tableGrob(printNodes)
grid.arrange(ggpl, tableNames, ncol=2, main="Monthly Data")
```

The idea is that instead of using `annotation_custom()` add text to a graphic device in the Grid graphics framework.